# SQL query to remove duplicate rows when using multiple unpivot statements in the same table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to figure out how to modify my SQL query so that I can have 2 unpivot statements to unpivot 2 sets of columns within my table.

Original Table Image:
[image]

Yellow highlighted fields are the columns I want to unpivot into the desired output table.

Desired Output Table:
[image]

Yellow highlighted fields are the unpivoted columns from the original table.

I have worked out the SQL query to unpivot the columns into my desired result but the issue is by using 2 unpivot statements in my query I end up creating a duplicate of each row. I have tried to use UNION to remove the duplicates but it doesn't work perfectly as in my Field 7A, Field 7B, and Field 7C columns; "NULL" is a possible value and they get marked as distinct rows and removed.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM
 my_table
UNPIVOT (Field_5 FOR Field_5_NAME IN (Field_5_A, Field_5_B, Field_5_C)
UNPIVOT (Field_7 FOR Field_7_NAME IN (Field_7_A, Field_7_B, Field_7_C)
```

[Sample Google Spreadsheet for reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CZ6_PaUd8T0uAEQ5MQ-pDoX7Nnon4dJVZvO2pBOLFDw/edit#gid=1425221949)

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add simple data/expected output as text so it can be easy for us to help ? Also please do not share external links, any additional data add it as text